# jquery after re-load, click doesn't work

Tags: jquery, load, bind

Link opens dropdown to choose sorting action. When sorted, page loads into itself with jquery load, and dropdown is closed. We can do that one more time. After that, link which opens dropdown doesn't work anymore and dropdown stays closed.

How to fix this? The main goal is to have a working (opening and closing) dropdown menu for sorting dynamic table. (dropdown is also dynamic, so it needs to be loaded with ajax request)

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- THIS IS DROPDOWN -->
    <div id="sortdropdown">
    <p><a href="" id="sortn">Name</a><br /><a href="" id="sortd">Date</a></p>
    </div>
    <!-- THIS IS LINK TO OPEN DROPDOWN -->
    <p><a href="" id="sortbutton">Sort by</a></p>            

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function doLoad(sort){
    var selector = "div#wrapper";
    $(selector).load('indexsort.php?act='+sort+' '+selector, function(){
        $('div#sortdropdown').hide();
        doBindings();
    });
}
function doBindings(){
    //sorts table on click - sorts by name
    $('a#sortn').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        doLoad('sn');
    });
    //sorts table on click - sorts by date
    $('a#sortd').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        doLoad('sd');
    });
    //opens/closes sort by dropdown menu
    $('a#sortbutton').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('div#sortdropdown').toggle();
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    //binds clicks so they are active after load method
    doBindings();
    //hides dropdown after landing
    $('div#sortdropdown').hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the bindings out of the doBindings() function, and use jQuery's [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function:

```
$('a#sortbutton').live("click",function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('div#sortdropdown').toggle();
});
```

Also, change your selectors.

`a#sortbutton` is less efficient than simply `#sortbutton`, as described in the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

> For id selectors, jQuery uses the
>   JavaScript function
>   document.getElementById(), which is
>   extremely efficient. When another
>   selector is attached to the id
>   selector, such as h2#pageTitle, jQuery
>   performs an additional check before
>   identifying the element as a match.

Comment: even more, if I do $('a#sortbutton').live ('click',function(event)... then link doesn't even work after first load

Comment: If you use `live()`, you shouldn't need to re-run `doBindings()` each time. `live()` 'Attach[es] a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.' so you should just be able to put that code at the global level.

Comment: Yes! It works! I put everything live() and out of doBindings() function. Thank you!

Comment: @Marko: Cool :) I've updated my answer with more description for the next person who comes along, and I've also added a performance improvement that you should implement.

Comment: There was also a solution witn unbind on dropdown link. Which one is easier on processing power and memory?

Comment: @Marko: I can't imagine that using either of them would make any noticeable difference to processing power or memory.  This isn't the 1970s, after all.  Personally, I would use `live()` as it makes for cleaner code.  It's up to you though.

Comment: @Town: when using live(), code looks more readable to me, so I'll go with that for now. Great tip for selectors, I stripped them immediately, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind) the click events in doLoad function before calling the indexsort.php file.

I won't recommend live because its very expensive method.

Comment: Do you have evidence to support that it's very expensive? Are we talking expensive in terms of microseconds?

Comment: This works too! I added unbind on a#sortbutton in doLoad function: $('a#sortbutton').unbind(); If this is better then live then this is the solution

Comment: @Marko and @Town: Check [this](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Go to Caveats heading.

Comment: I can't really see anything in there that suggest performance would be noticeably reduced through using `live()` in this context.  @Marko: I think it's safe to use whichever you prefer. Definitely change your selectors though - `a#sortbutton` is unnecessarily heavy.